# Negative Sell Trades — what do I need to do now?

Tags: trading, shorting-securities, cfd, crude-oil

I'm new to trading. I'm trading crude oil CFDs. I'm holding a short position of 400 barrels of crude oil at $37.50, but the price of crude oil is now $41.50.

During the move from $37.50 to $41.50, my losses increased due to the short position of 400 barrels.

Right now I only have the 400 barrels short position. The loss is $1400 while my total fund is $1700.

Please tell me what I can do to save my money and withdraw it.

Comment: I've edited your question. Please check that I have not accidentally changed the meaning of your post during my edit.

Comment: By "sell position", do you mean "short position"?

Comment: yes @Flux it's short position

Comment: You could close the short position at a loss of $1400, and withdraw whatever you have left in your account.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. Hope that the price goes down. The money IS GONE. If the price goes up a little, then - well - you lost it all.

"I'm new to trading." - ah, "I am new to driving, I crashed my car, please help me getting the car back". New to trading: NO EXCUSE - you are an adult, you opened those orders. If you are new, you should be on a simulator. TAKING RESPONSIBILITY IS WHAT MAKES MONEY IN TRADING. You basically lost money because of a failure to take responsibility for your trading success. And 400 barrel on a 1700 USD account - HIGHLY BRUTALLY IRRESPONSIBLE. You did not trade, you did bet and you lost. You do not "ONLY" have 400 barrels short - this are maybe 300 too many.

The 1400 are a loss. There is no way to get this money back at this price.

Comment: Update: And the price is coming down - looks like OP is more lucky than he deserves.